# PHP Como fazer um loop especifico para cada tabela?

Tags: php

Boa Tarde

Tenho uma tabela no **MYSQL**

```
 <?php 
 $pesquisa = "SELECT * From tabelaProdutos";

 ID / Código / Descrição /    Qtd
 1  /0001   / Caixa Azul 1/   1
 2  /0002   / Caixa Azul 2/   3
 3  /0003   / Caixa branca 1/ 12
 4  /0001   / Caixa Preta 1/  11
```

Como faço para cada loop eu colocar uma condição diferente.

> Preciso que o usuário receba as tabelas separadas por descrição
>   conforme os exemplos abaixo.

Exemplo
**Tabela 1**

```
 ID / Código / Descrição /    Qtd
 1  /0001   / Caixa Azul 1/   1
 2  /0002   / Caixa Azul 2/   3
```

**Tabela 2**

```
3  /0003   / Caixa branca 1/ 12
```

**Tabela 3**

```
4  /0001   / Caixa Preta 1/  11
```

Eu precio fazer um **SELECT** para cada tabela ? Ou tem alguma forma mais fácil e correta para fazer isso ?

Obrigado

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, não entendi muito bem o que precisa

Comment: São tres tabelas do bd diferentes?

Comment: Não. Preciso gerar no html as 3 tabelas, mas gostaria saber para cada tabela eu preciso criar um SELECT diferente, ou somente um SELECT eu consigo fazer as 3 tabelas no html

Comment: Fica complicado dizer se não sabemos as condições que você quer usar para separar os dados em 3 conjuntos.

Comment: Pela descrição, uma para caixa azul, outra pra caixa branca e outra para caixa preta

Comment: Na verdade tanto faz, você pode fazer uma query só e 3 loops, ou 3 queries e 3 loops.

Comment: Como exemplo tenho esse loop <?php while ($dado = $resultado->fetch_array()) { ?>, como posso fazer a condição para a descrição

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você não quer que repita as linhas da tabela quando for a mesma. Use o comando abaixo.

```
SELECT DISTINCT descricao
FROM tabelaProdutos
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você não quer que repita as linhas da tabela quando for a mesma. Use o comando abaixo.

```
SELECT DISTINCT descricao
FROM tabelaProdutos
```

Comment: Na verdade não é isso a tabela no html utilizando uma query e loop, preciso que uma query fazer outros loops com a condição de descrições diferentes